# How to detect samba locked files programmatically?

Tags: linux, samba, lazarus

How can I get a list of files locked by samba programmatically?

There is a command smbstatus which will give you that information. But I want to get that info within my program (written in Lazarus). One method is to run smbstatus as a child process and parse the output. I am trying to directly get the required info within the program (using an API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing the smbstatus output is a fairly sensible thing to do.

You might also be able to access some of this information using libsmbsharemodes, which is a part of Samba.